# "du -sh" permission denied

Tags: bash, size, permission-denied

I want to know some folders size, I have permissions to those folders, but not to their contents and when I try "du -sh" , it shows me "permission denied". Can anyone help me with this problem ? How can I get folders size without having permissions inside that folder ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access, just run it with sudo:

`sudo du -sh ./*`